# Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't understand why I keep getting this error. Anyone can help me understand why this error is coming up, would be much appreciated. I am trying to update a large database and trying to replace the default location string for all the attachments with 'D:'. I feel like I am close, but I do not understand this error. This query successfully loops through all my table names saved in @Tables, but at each one I get the error. Here is my code...
 Error: Must declare the scalar variable "@oldPath"

```
DECLARE @newPath VARCHAR(500);
SET @newPath = 'D:\temp';

DECLARE @oldPath VARCHAR(500);
SET @oldPath = (SELECT Value FROM Settings WHERE Name = 'AttachmentDirectoryPath');



DECLARE @Tables TABLE
(
    myTableName VARCHAR(500)
)

insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('WorkOrderMasterAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('BillOfMaterialAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('CustomerAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('ToolAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('FacilityAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('LocationAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('AssetAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('ContractorAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('VendorAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('WorkOrderAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('ClosedWorkOrderAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('EmployeeAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('PurchaseOrderAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('PurchaseOrderHistoryAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('PartAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('AssetSystemAttachments');

DECLARE cursor_tables cursor
FOR SELECT myTableName from @Tables

OPEN cursor_tables

DECLARE @loopTableName VARCHAR(100)

fetch next from cursor_tables
into @loopTableName

DECLARE @updateSql VARCHAR(2000);

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN   

    SET @updateSql = ' UPDATE ' + @loopTableName + 
                 ' SET Path = REPLACE(Path,@oldPath,@newPath)'

    --print @updateSql
    EXEC(@updatesql)

    fetch next from cursor_tables
    into @loopTableName
END 

CLOSE cursor_tables
DEALLOCATE cursor_tables
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be a LOT simpler to just write your 15-16 update statements instead of doing this in a loop? It would take a lot less typing and it would be much simpler.

Comment: Yes, but I will be loading @Tables with all tables with names LIKE '%Attachments%' instead of all the insert statements.

Comment: Even if you are using dynamic sql I would NOT use a loop for this. Use dynamic sql to build the sql statements and execute it all at once.

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer for an example of using dynamic sql without a loop for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SP_EXECUTESQL` to pass values to variables inside dynamic query

```
DECLARE @updateSql NVARCHAR(2000) -- important 

SET @updateSql = ' UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@loopTableName) + 
             ' SET Path = REPLACE(Path,@oldPath,@newPath)'

--print @updateSql
EXEC sp_executesql @updatesql,
     N'@oldPath VARCHAR(500),@newPath VARCHAR(500)',
       @oldPath = @oldPath, @newPath = @newPath
```

[sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) requires `@stmt` parameter to be of `NVARCHAR` type so change the datatype of `@updateSql` from `VARCHAR` to `NVARCHAR`

Answer (score 1):

Strings don't automatically know that they contain variables.  So, forget about `EXEC()` as a general method for executing dynamic SQL.  Remember:  `sp_executesql` instead make the inner loop:

```
SET @updateSql = ' UPDATE ' + @loopTableName + 
             ' SET Path = REPLACE(Path, @oldPath, @newPath)'

exec sp_executesql @updatesql,
     N'@oldPath varchar(500), @newPath varchar(500)',
     @oldPath = @oldPath, @newPath = @newPath;
```

This will execute the SQL and assign the variables.  Note:  You cannot pass in the table name as a parameter into the query, so you still need to provide that directly in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much simpler approach than using a loop for what is likely not something you need to run very frequently.

```
DECLARE @newPath VARCHAR(500) = 'D:\temp';

DECLARE @oldPath VARCHAR(500);
SELECT @oldPath = Value 
FROM Settings 
WHERE Name = 'AttachmentDirectoryPath'

update WorkOrderMasterAttachments SET Path = REPLACE(Path, @oldPath, @newPath)
update BillOfMaterialAttachments SET Path = REPLACE(Path, @oldPath, @newPath)
update CustomerAttachments SET Path = REPLACE(Path, @oldPath, @newPath)
update ToolAttachments SET Path = REPLACE(Path, @oldPath, @newPath)
update FacilityAttachments SET Path = REPLACE(Path, @oldPath, @newPath)
update LocationAttachments SET Path = REPLACE(Path, @oldPath, @newPath)
update AssetAttachments SET Path = REPLACE(Path, @oldPath, @newPath)
update ContractorAttachments SET Path = REPLACE(Path, @oldPath, @newPath)
update VendorAttachments SET Path = REPLACE(Path, @oldPath, @newPath)
update WorkOrderAttachments SET Path = REPLACE(Path, @oldPath, @newPath)
update ClosedWorkOrderAttachments SET Path = REPLACE(Path, @oldPath, @newPath)
update EmployeeAttachments SET Path = REPLACE(Path, @oldPath, @newPath)
update PurchaseOrderAttachments SET Path = REPLACE(Path, @oldPath, @newPath)
update PurchaseOrderHistoryAttachments SET Path = REPLACE(Path, @oldPath, @newPath)
update PartAttachments SET Path = REPLACE(Path, @oldPath, @newPath)
update AssetSystemAttachments SET Path = REPLACE(Path, @oldPath, @newPath)
```

--EDIT--

Since you stated that you really want to use a table to get all the table names to update here is an approach using dynamic sql that doesn't need a loop. It builds up a long string of sql statements to update each table but doesn't use a loop. I realize that the performance of 15-16 iterations isn't much but this example is a way to avoid to loops and in my opinion is much easier code to debug. It is also for me to conceptualize this type of thing instead of using a loop.

```
DECLARE @Tables TABLE
(
    myTableName VARCHAR(500)
)

insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('WorkOrderMasterAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('BillOfMaterialAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('CustomerAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('ToolAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('FacilityAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('LocationAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('AssetAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('ContractorAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('VendorAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('WorkOrderAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('ClosedWorkOrderAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('EmployeeAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('PurchaseOrderAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('PurchaseOrderHistoryAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('PartAttachments');
insert into @Tables(myTableName) values ('AssetSystemAttachments');

declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'Update ' + myTableName + ' set Path = REPLACE(Path,@oldPath,@newPath);'
from @Tables

select @SQL

exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@oldPath varchar(500), @newPath varchar(500)', @oldPath = @oldPath, @newPath = @newPath
```

Comment: That is interesting. I like that and will probably use this instead of the loop. I ended up loading @Tables with this:
INSERT INTO @Tables(myTableName)
 SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%Attachments%'

Comment: You could skip the table variable entirely and just use sys.tables. I would hope you are including the schema in your code. And if so you shouldn't use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES to determine the schema. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224.aspx